# Как создать VPS на Debian

Tags: сервер, debian, виртуальная-машина

У меня есть сервер, на нем установлен Debian. На нем крутятся сайты. Могу ли я еще на него поставить ***виртуалку***, чтобы отдать ее другу и он мог пользоваться ею для себя. Или это не реально?

Comment: А сервер - это Ваш локальный комп? Или VPS/VDS? Если это Ваш, то IP статический или динамический?

Comment: сервер я арендую, ip статическая

Comment: Т.е. Вы в виртуалке хотите поставить виртуалку? Если это так, то я бы на Вашем месте это сразу отразил бы в вопросе. Возможно тогда бы Вы не угробили бы сервер советом от gbg.

Comment: у меня не виртуалка, это физический сервер

Comment: Т.е. Вы арендуете физический сервер в стойке? Вы его видели? Щупали?

Comment: нет, а как узнать виртуалка это или нет?

Comment: Вы заказывали выделенный (dedicated) сервер? Или просто сервер (VPS/VDS)? В первом случае аренда обойдется в несколько раз дороже (это будет не 3-5$ за минимальную конфигурацию). В первом случае после оплаты пройдет не пара минут, а в лучшем случае несколько часов, а то и дней, пока под Вас соберется конкретная конфигурация. Это же физическая машина. Ее физически нужно собрать (память вставить, винт, проц и т.п.). Никто ее держать "прозапас" и жечь электроэнергию не будет.

Comment: Также можно посмотреть характеристики процессора командой ***cat /proc/cpuinfo*** . В результате у Вас машина на 2 ядра, а в характеристиках Вы увидите, что у Вашего процессора 10 ядер. Какой вывод сделаете? Можно также посмотреть тот же диск командой ***lshw -C disk***. Смотрите его, а его... нет :) Вообще, даже виртуальные сервера различаются. Так на виртуальной машине Вы сможете управлять ядром, а на виртуальном контейнере - нет. Второй конечно же дешевле обходится.

Comment: насколько я понял, команда ***cat /proc/cpuinfo*** выводит, что у меня 7 ядер. за сервер я плачу 30 евро и брал его как выделеный сервер

Comment: Вот и вопрос... если это полноценный выделенный сервер, то почему 7 ядер, а не 8? Я так глубоко не сведущ, но бывают ли 7-ми ядерные процессоры?

Comment: я не очень шарю в том выводе) может там и 8 пишет)

Answer (score 1):

Можете. Реально. Вариантов - огромное количество, начиная с казуального Virtual Box и заканчивая взрослыми гипервизорами [QEMU/KVM](http://xgu.ru/wiki/KVM) и [XEN](http://xgu.ru/wiki/xen).

Comment: а можете посоветовать какой то? главное, что бы не очень сложный, в тоже время и не очень простой. желательно бесплатный) и плюсом будет, если будет хорошая документация на рус языке. кстати, работаю через консоль

Comment: @Diefair - я добавил в ответ пару ссылок, почитайте материал.

Comment: спасибо, буду еще смотреть, пока вышло только сервер угробить